# How do you edit a Scribunto-based MediaWiki template?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates, scribunto

I have imported a few templates to my wiki from Wikipedia. I believe most of them use Scribunto. None of this was a problem until recently, when I needed to edit one of them.

The template in question is Wikipedia's `{{Key press}}`. The source code seems to be quite empty:

```
<includeonly>{{{{{♥|safesubst:}}}#invoke:key|keypress}}</includeonly><noinclude>
{{documentation}}
</noinclude>
```

My question is this: where do you find the actual source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{#invoke:key|keypress}}` calls the `keypress` method in the object returned by [Module:Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Key).